Response with Chart in Gradio
I see here some cases where plotly charts can be used (https://www.gradio.app/guides/creating-a-custom-chatbot-with-blocks) . I think the example with fig is broken here .
Does anybody have experience working with Multimodal mode that looks address responding with plotly chart to user .
Thanks

basically you just need to pass the filename to the chatbot and it will visualize the plot:
import gradio as gr
import plotly.express as px
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def random_plot():
    df = px.data.iris()
    fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                    size='petal_length', hover_data=['petal_width'])
    
    # save plot into temp file
    ff = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".jpg", delete=False)
    print(ff.name)
    fig.write_image(ff)
    messages = [(None,(ff.name,))]
    return messages


with gr.Blocks(fill_height=True) as demo:

    chatbot = gr.Chatbot(
        value = random_plot,
        elem_id="chatbot",
    )


demo.launch()

